# Cambodia Alphabets issue on delivery slip

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I got a issue with Prestashop 1.7.4.2 delivery slip that it is not recognizing Khmer letters. Can anyone please help  with which font I can use it to make this letters display.

[image]

I had added supported fonts in \override\classes\pdf\PDFGenerator.php but it is not working.

Comment: It can be a file encoding file issue or database encoding issue

Comment: @tarek But for other fonts, it is working fine like TH etc.

Comment: What is the library behind "PDFGenerator.php"? Mostly not work with Khmer Unicode, it can be OK, if do from HTML to PDF.

Comment: @Osify TCPD library

Comment: @Tijojoel I have answered, it might help you, please use the font I stated and the result should be like this: https://i1.wp.com/ask.osify.com/files/2020/07/image-2.png?resize=768%2C353&ssl=1

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 
`fc-match -s ":lang=km" | head -10`
shows

```sh
KhmerOS.ttf: "Khmer OS" "Regular"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
NimbusSans-Regular.otf: "Nimbus Sans" "Regular"
Loma.ttf: "Loma" "Regular"
Waree.ttf: "Waree" "Regular"
Umpush-Bold.ttf: "Umpush" "Bold"
Laksaman.ttf: "Laksaman" "Regular"
NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Regular"
```

So, DejaVuSans is font you are looking for.

PDFGeneratorCore uses [helvetica](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php#L32) as default font.
Try to set **en** language by [PDFGeneratorCore::setFontForLang($iso_lang)](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php#L160) or just use **en** language globally to choose **[DejaVuSans](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php#L69)**

Comment: I had added the changed in my override PDFGenerator.php file, instead of question marks now it is coming boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my explanation at: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11677

I could make it works at mPDF and should be the same with TCPDF, you need a custom font for Khmer, you can try to use this: [Khmer OS Siemreap](https://github.com/Seuksa/iTextKhmer/blob/master/src/main/resources/KhmerOSSiemreap.ttf).